# PHP help needed with if statement and or

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have this if statement that I cannot figure it out:

`<?php if($isFriend = true || $isOwner = true){echo $height;}else{/* do nothing*/}?>`

the above code should be doing if is friend and or is owner then display height else display nothing.

I don't see why its wrong and its not doing what I want.

Comment: You are using `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (comparison).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using assignments instead of comparisons:

```
$isFriend = true;
```

is an assignment

```
$isFriend == true;
```

is a comparison. But with values that are already booleans, you really don't need to compare them with `true`.

```
if ($isFriend || $isOwner) …
```

would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use  `==` instead of  `=`

`==` equal will check equality while singe `=` is used to assign value to a variable.
So you need to change to:

```
<?php if($isFriend == true || $isOwner == true){echo $height;}else{/* do nothing*/}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning instead of comparing.
But don't use `==` please use `===`
because in php the `==` operator is coercive.

Also in general it is bad practice to write

```
if ($condition === true) {...}
```

prefer

```
if ($condition) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<?php if($isFriend || $isOwner){echo $height;}else{/* do nothing*/}?>
```

No need to check if value of a variable is true or not just put it as an condition.

Now the comparison you were trying you need to usee `==` to compare between any two things example for your code.

```
<?php if($isFriend == true || $isOwner == true){echo $height;}else{/* do nothing*/}?>
```

**NOTE:** It is highly recommended to use`===` instead of `==` to do stick checking and avoid type conversion.